# Use MDX to get client status given a defined date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, mdx

Using MDX to return for each client, their latest status within a defined date range.

**Sample Dataset:**

```
Client | Status   | Date
A      | Pending  | 30-Jun-12
A      | Pending  | 01-Jul-12
A      | Active  | 02-Jul-12
A      | Active  | 03-Jul-12
B      | Pending  | 01-Jun-12
B      | Active  | 02-Jun-12
B      | Active  | 03-Jun-12
B      | Active  | 04-Jun-12
```

**Additional Info:**
(No records for client A after 3-Jul-12 as they no longer receive a service)
(No records for client B after 4-Jun-12 as they no longer receive a service)

**REQUIRED OUTPUT:**
If Date dimension is filtered for all of June 2012 it should return

```
Client | Status   | Date
A      | Pending  | 30-Jun-12
B      | Active  | 04-Jun-12
```

**Environment:**
SSAS 2005 | SS 2008 R2 | VS 2008

Hoping to use calculated member or named set but any help/guidance greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

As you are missing a lot of detail, I just assume the missing information:

- Multi select is not required.
- Your client hierarchy is named `[Client].[Client]`.
- Your Status hierarchy is named `[Status].[Status]`, i. e. it is on a different dimension from the `Client` dimension.
- Your date hierarchy is named `[Date].[Date]` with day level `[Date].[Date].[Day]` and month level `[Date].[Date].[Day]`.
- The June 2012 member key is `201206`.
- The measure group connecting the above dimensions is called `Sales`.
- Your cube is named `Cube`.

Then

```
WITH   Set [Days] as
           Descendants([Date].[Date].CurrentMember, [Date].[Date].[Day])
       Member [Measures].[Date] as 
              Exists([Days], {[Client].[Client].CurrentMember}, 'Sales')
                    .Item(Exists([Days], {[Client].[Client].CurrentMember}, 'Sales').Count - 1)
                    .Item(0)
                    .Name
SELECT { [Measures].[Date] }
       ON COLUMNS,
       NON EMPTY
       [Client].[Client].[Client].Members
       *
       [Status].[Status].[Status].Members
       ON ROWS
  FROM [Cube]
 WHERE [Date].[Date].[Month].&[201206]
```

should deliver what you want.

The `[Days]` set contains all days in the filtered date range. Then, the `Date` measure is calculated as follows: The `Exists` restricts the `Days` to those of the current client, the first `Item` extracts the last tuple from this set, the second `Item` converts this to a member, and then the name of this member is returned as the `Date` measure.

**EDIT**

To get not one row per status, but the last status (assuming there is at most one record per day), you could turn the status to a measure as well:

```
WITH   Set [Days] as
           Descendants([Date].[Date].CurrentMember, [Date].[Date].[Day])
       Member [Measures].[Date] as 
              Exists([Days], {[Client].[Client].CurrentMember}, 'Sales')
                    .Item(Exists([Days], {[Client].[Client].CurrentMember}, 'Sales').Count - 1)
                    .Item(0)
                    .Name
       Member [Measures].[Status] as 
              Exists([Status].[Status].[Status].Members,
                     { Exists([Days], {[Client].[Client].CurrentMember}, 'Sales')
                            .Item(Exists([Days], {[Client].[Client].CurrentMember}, 'Sales').Count - 1)
                     },
                     'Sales'
                    )
                    .Item(0)
                    .Item(0)
                    .Name
SELECT { [Measures].[Status], [Measures].[Date] }
       ON COLUMNS,
       NON EMPTY
       [Client].[Client].[Client].Members
       ON ROWS
  FROM [Cube]
 WHERE [Date].[Date].[Month].&[201206]
```

The outer `Exists` of the `Status` measure finds the one element set containing the status for the date, which is then converted via two `Item(0)` calls to a member, from which we can get the name.

Comment: Thanks for the effort Frank. Getting close but I'm finding the set is returning multiple records for some clients where the client has a status change during the defined period. i.e. Returns the last occurrence of every status change.

Comment: No luck, still returning multiple rows per client. Discovered this approach to be very slow. I'm gonna try and tackle this from another angle. Maybe a snapshot dimension or similar. Thanks for your help.